# Adding Elements In a List Scheme

Tags: scheme, iteration

In Scheme, I am trying to iterate through a list adding each element from a portion of the list.

For example, if I had ((1 2 5) (1 2) (1 5) (1) (2 5) (2) (5) ()) for a list, I am trying to add the first part ( 1 2 5 ) and then the second part ( 1 2 ) and so on in order to see if each element adds up to a specific number.

Hope this makes sense, tried my best to explain this.

If someone could help me figure this problem out, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the numbers of a (small) list you can use `apply`:

```
> (apply + '(1 2 3))
6
```

which is the same as

```
> (+ 1 2 3)
6
```

In order to apply this to a list of sublists, use `map`:

```
(define (f lst)
  (map (lambda (sublst) (apply + sublst))
       lst))

> (f '((1 2 5) (1 2) (1 5) (1) (2 5) (2) (5) ()))
'(8 3 6 1 7 2 5 0)
```

For larger list you might want to replace `apply` by `foldl` or equivalent.

Comment: Thank you!! This is exactly what I was looking for.